# create a dataframe with 2 lists in R

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have 2 lists, header and data.

```
a <- c('header1', 'header2', 'header3')
b <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

I want to create a dataframe like this with a is the header.

```
header1 header2 header3
1 2 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
a <- c('header1', 'header2', 'header3')
b <- c(1, 2, 3)

x <- data.frame(t(b))

colnames(x) <- a
```